# I want to load the data from XML file and show in the listbox?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a three classes:

First is Person:

```
    public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }



    public Person()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " +LastName + "\t" +Email;
    }
}
```

Second is:

```
     public class Student:Person
{

    public Student()
    {
    }
    public double AssessmentGrade { get; set; }
    public double AssignmentGrade { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," +AssessmentGrade + "," + AssignmentGrade;
    }
}
```

Third is:

```
   public class Teacher:Person
{
    public int RoomNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "," + RoomNumber;
    }
}
```

I have One more class where i just call the data from PeronDB (Class)

```
    public class Persons
{
     private List<Person> persons = null;

       public void Fill()
    {
        persons = PersonDB.GetPersons();
    }
 }
```

InPersonDB class I am doing if its Student node then read the data if its Teacher nodes then also reads the data and If it Person it also reads the data.

```
    public class PersonDB
{
    private const string path = @"..\..\Persons.xml";

    public static List<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;

        XmlReader xmlIn = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

        if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Student"))
        {
            do
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                Student student = (Student)person;
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Student");
                student.FirstName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                student.LastName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                student.Email = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                student.AssessmentGrade = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                student.AssignmentGrade = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsInt();

                persons.Add(student);
            } while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Student"));

        }

        else if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Teacher"))
        {
            do
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                Teacher teacher = (Teacher)person;
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Teacher");
                teacher.FirstName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                teacher.LastName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                teacher.Email = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                teacher.RoomNumber = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsInt();

                persons.Add(teacher);
            } while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Teacher"));
        }

        if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Person"))
        {
            do
            {
                Person person = new Person();

                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Person");
                person.FirstName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                person.LastName = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                person.Email = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();

                persons.Add(person);
            } while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Person"));
        }


        xmlIn.Close();

        return persons;
    }
   }
```

And in the Form Load i am doing:

```
     Persons personList = null;

        private void FillPersonlstBox()
    {
        Person p;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < personList.Count; i++)
        {
            p = personList[i];
            listBox1.Items.Add(p.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personList.Changed += new Persons.ChangeHandler(HandleChange);
        personList.Fill();
        FillPersonlstBox();
    }
```

It show me in ** personList.Changed += new Persons.ChangeHandler(HandleChange); ** this line error.It shows me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." this error.
Please guys help me How to fix it?

Comment: personList  = new Persons ();

Comment: the variable personList is null. you should instantiate  befor you use it.

Comment: Now it gives me **"{Unable to cast object of type 'Collection.Person' to type 'Collection.Student'."}** this error :( System.InvalidCastException         It show me in PersonDB Class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point you've got to instantiate `personList`.

In your code, you can't handle the `Changed` event on personList because it is still null.

So instead of

```
Persons personList = null;
```

Maybe try

```
Persons personList = new Persons();
```

Comment: it gives me still error  **"{Unable to cast object of type 'Collection.Person' to type 'Collection.Student'."}** this error :( System.InvalidCastException in PersonDB Class

Comment: @user1050667 Sorry I missed your comment earlier.  Do you want to try troubleshooting this here or post a new question?